# Example of using cairo in python3 for vectorial animations

Tags: qt, python-3.x, gtk, cairo, pycairo

I'd like to display some simple game/interactive vector drawings using `pycairo` and `python3`.

I think I'll also need a "widget toolkit" to manage creating the window itself since I don't think `pycairo` can do that part alone (it only saves output to files).

I've looked into `PySide` (based on `Qt`, seems pretty complex) and `gi` (based on gtk3 I guess, there's even `gi-cairo` but couldn't find a tutorial or example). I don't really know how to integrate those with `pycairo`.

I heard of `pygame` but doesn't seem to be supported on `python3` (at least I have no python3-pygame showing up in apt).

Can I have a starter example of using `pycairo` with `python3` and some standard windowing toolkit to create a window and draw some simple animation?

**EDIT:** Bonus points if the example is animated.

Comment: Use Qt: it has its own painting facilities (including SVG) which are better and faster than Cairo (yes, I've tried both). I think the APIs quite similar: the concept of paths stays the same. If you're interested, @reply here and I'll give more details. I'd post an example too, but the question is about Cairo...

Comment: I am, do you want me to add Qt to the keywords? Please go ahead and post this as an answer.

Comment: @GiovanniFunchal How do you want to draw these animations? From an animated SVG file? Frame by frame? By modifying graphical primitives?

Comment: I plan to draw it by a mix of displaying svgs and drawing with primitives (lines, shapes, etc)

Answer (score 0):

This is a full application in PySide that displays a (possibly animated) SVG file on screen:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QtSvg.QSvgWidget('animation.svg')
widget.show()

app.exec_()
```

And here's another example that uses the Graphics View Framework to animate a weird vector shape:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

path = QPainterPath()
path.quadTo(0,20, 20,20)
path.lineTo(10,10)

item = QGraphicsPathItem(path)

timer = QTimeLine(5000)
timer.setFrameRange(0, 100)

ani = QGraphicsItemAnimation()
ani.setItem(item)
ani.setTimeLine(timer)

ani.setPosAt(1, QPointF(200,200))
ani.setRotationAt(1, 360)
ani.setScaleAt(1, 3,3)

scene = QGraphicsScene(0,0, 300,300)
scene.addItem(item)

view = QGraphicsView(scene)
view.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing)
view.show()

timer.start()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: This is a nice example for Qt, it's not so good if (like me) you landed here looking for an example with cairo and Gtk though.   - Not sure, if it's possible, but can the question be changed to example of using Qt for vector animation ?

Comment: While there is an effort to provide a complete code for displaying a SVG file in QT, it has nothing to do with `cairo` or `pycairo`. Like @StuartAxon, I was directed here while searching for an interactive use of `pycairo`. -1 to put search engines off from suggesting it.